# Post large files to Dropbox

Tags: c#, dropbox, spring.net, spring-social

Is there any way to post large files (>150MB) to Dropbox service with Spring Social library?
I'm always getting a connection error:

> WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly) if I try to upload a large file.

It's a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Spring Social uses the [DropBox REST API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api).

There is a 150MB limit on uploading files for all clients that use the REST API. If you want to upload larger files you'll have to do so through the Dropbox desktop application.

You can find this in the Dropbox REST API SDK:

- [Uploading files (PUT)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files_put) (under notes)

As far as I can see from the Spring Social implementation it is indeed REST based.

Comment: Do you know of any other API which supports large files/is non-REST?

Comment: Waiting for chunked upload: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNETSOCIALDB-12

Comment: To upload larger files, use the /chunked_upload instead (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#chunked-upload). However as Alexey points out this is still to be implemented in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

To upload files larger than 150 MB using Dropbox REST API, we can use "Upload sessions". As per documentation:-

> Upload sessions allow you to upload a single file in one or more requests, for example where the size of the file is greater than 150 MB. This call starts a new upload session with the given data. You can then use upload_session/append:2 to add more data and upload_session/finish to save all the data to a file in Dropbox.
>   A single request should not upload more than 150 MB. The maximum size of a file one can upload to an upload session is 350 GB.

Check below link for clear understanding

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload_session-start